# Data wont save on roblox studio

Tags: database, lua, roblox

so I am still very new to lua and i was wondering why this script wont work? theres no errors and i have already searched for a solution. im trying to use data store

```
    'local datastorage = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local datastore =  datastorage:GetDataStore("datastore")
--defenitions
local player = game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue")
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Parent = leaderstats
    local id = "player_"..player.UserId
    -- load player id and data
    local data
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        data = datastore:GetAsync(id)
--message
    end)
    cash.Value = datastore
    if success then
        print("iffy")
    end
end)



game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local data = player.leaderstats.Cash.value
    local playerid = "player_"..player.UserId
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        
    
        datastore:GetAsync(playerid, data)
    end)
    if success then
        print("yes!")
    else
        print("error check script")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
'
```

Comment: Are you testing this in studio? Also are you using the same key to load the data as well as save the data

Comment: i think i did use the same key to save and load the data. and yes im using this on studio right now

Comment: Make sure that you have studio access to api services on (inside settings -> security)

Comment: already made sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing get async when the player is removing

```lua
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local data = player.leaderstats.Cash.value
    local playerid = "player_"..player.UserId
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        
    
        --datastore:GetAsync(playerid, data) -- switch to SetAsync
        datastore:SetAsync(playerid, data)
    end)
    if success then
        print("yes!")
    else
        print("error check script")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
```